# After ajax request php function not receiving variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a searcher and I made a function that gets the data from a db, saves each ad in a variable and saves pagination (from another function) in another variable, so they can be returned in an array to be printed in the html later.

It works like this: you hit a buy or rent button and you go to the search page (/search?do?=buy/rent) then you have to select the property type, optionally a city/zone and hit search. Ajax sends the data via post (to search.php, the same file), hides the first container and shows the second container that has the list of properties with a pagination at the end of the page.

These are the main variables and a script to hide/show containers:

```
$mode           = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'do', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // buy or rent
$prop_type      = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prop_type', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // res or com AJAX
$city           = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'city', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); // AJAX
$zone           = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'zone', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); // AJAX
$page_number    = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

if (isset($page_number) && $page_number >= 1) {
    $cont1 = 'display: none;';
    $cont2 = NULL;
    // need a way to get the prop_type (the checked checkbox before changing the page) without using $_GET.
} else {
    $cont1 = NULL;
    $cont2 = 'display: none;';
}
```

This is the function:

```
function get_prop_data($prop_type, $city, $zone, $page_number, $table, $targetpage) {

    if ($prop_type == 'res') {
        $table2 = 'res_prop';
    } else if ($prop_type == 'com') {
        $table2 = 'com_prop';
    }

    if ($city != 0) {
        $optional_cond = ' WHERE t2.city = ' . $city;
        $optional_cond2 = NULL;

        if ($zone != 0) {
            $optional_cond2 = ' AND t2.zone = ' . $zone;
        }
    } else $optional_cond = $optional_cond2 = NULL;

    $mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'db', '123456', 'name');

    // pagination
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ' . $table)) {
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($totalitems);

        $stmt->fetch();

        if (!isset($page)) {
            $page = (int)$page_number <= 0 ? 1 : (int)$page_number;
        }

        $limit = 4;

        if ($page > ceil($totalitems / $limit)) {
            $page = ceil($totalitems / $limit);
        }

        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;

        $stmt->close();

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(' SELECT t1.id, t2.*
                                       FROM ' . $table . ' t1
                                       INNER JOIN ' . $table2 . ' t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
                                       ' . $optional_cond . $optional_cond2 . '
                                       LIMIT ?, ?')) {
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $start, $limit);
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->bind_result($id, $id, $type, $status, $bhk, $baths, $area1, $area2, $age, $description, $price, $city, $zone, $img1, $img2, $img3, $img4);
            $test = "";
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                if ($status === 0) {
                    $possesion = 'En construcción';
                } else if ($status === 1 || $status === 2) {
                    $possesion = 'Inmediata';
                } else $possesion = 'Desconocida';
                if ($prop_type == 'res') {
                    $is_res = '<p><span class="bath">Bed</span>: <span class="two">' . $bhk . ' BHK</span></p>
                            <p><span class="bath1">Baths</span>: <span class="two">' . $baths . '</span></p>';
                } else $is_res = NULL;
                $test .= '<div class="box-col">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 left-side ">
                            <a href="/single?id=' . $id . '"> <img class="img-responsive" src="' . $img1 . '" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 middle-side">
                            <h4>Disponibilidad: ' . $possesion . '</h4>
                            ' . $is_res . '
                            <p><span class="bath2">Built-up Area</span>: <span class="two">' . $area1 . ' m²</span></p>
                            <p><span class="bath3">Plot Area</span>: <span class="two">' . $area2 . ' m²</span></p>
                            <p><span class="bath4">Age of property</span>: <span class="two">' . $age . ' Year(s)</span></p>
                            <p><span class="bath5">Price</span>: <span class="two">' . $price . ' €</span></p>
                            <div class="right-side">
                                <a href="/contact" class="hvr-sweep-to-right more">Contact Builder</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    </div>
';
                $pagination = functions::getPaginationString($page, $totalitems, $limit, $adjacents = 1, $targetpage, $pagestring = "&page=");
            }
        } //else echo "Statement failed: " . $mysqli->error . "<br>";
    } //else echo "Statement failed: " . $mysqli->error . "<br>";

    return array($test, $pagination);
}
```

This is the main code:

```
if (empty($_GET)) {
    echo 'under construction';
}
else if (isset($mode) && $mode == 'buy') {
    $table = 'to_sell';
    $targetpage = '/search?do=buy';;

    if (isset($prop_type)) {
        $data = get_prop_data($prop_type, $city, $zone, $page_number, $table, $targetpage);
        $test = $data[0];
        $pagination = $data[1];
    }
}
else if (isset($mode) && $mode == 'rent') {
    $table = 'to_rent';
    $targetpage = '/search?do=rent';;

    if (isset($prop_type)) {
        $data = get_prop_data($prop_type, $city, $zone, $page_number, $table, $targetpage);
        $test = $data[0];
        $pagination = $data[1];
    }
}
else {
    echo 'invalid url';
}
```

This is the AJAX script that sends the checkbox value via post (it's not working correctly, I don't get an undefined error in `$prop_type` (I don't know why???) but I get it in `$table2`, that it's inside the `if ($prop_type == '')`):

```
$('.search, .pagination').click(function() { // search button and change page

    if ($('#res_prop').is(':checked')) {
        $prop_type = $('#res_prop').val();
    }
    else if ($('#com_prop').is(':checked')) {
        $prop_type = $('#com_prop').val();
    }

    $.post('search.php', { // same file, maybe self
        prop_type: $prop_type,
        city: $('select[name=city]').val(), // optional
        zone: $('select[name=zone]').val(), // option value="0" by default
        success: function(){
            $('.cont-1').hide();
            $('.cont-2').show();
        }
    });

});
```

It works perfectly if I manually set `$prop_type = 'res';`. Any ideas?

Another problem is that the pagination buttons link does not work, it just triggers the ajax script (they need to send the data, otherwise the script will restart when changing pages).

I really would appreciate any optimization to the scripts. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your syntax is off from the [jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Does that mean I can't send `prop_type` to `search.php` and execute again the whole php script without reloading? sorry i've never used ajax, i'm totally lost.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that.  I didn't look at an answer for you, but from the syntax, the success call should not be part of the data object.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing your javascript and php here.

In PHP you declare a variable with $varname, in Javascript, $ represents the jQuery operator.  As such your code that says $prop_type is totally invalid since this is javascript code.  You're telling jQuery to execute some functionality called prop_type which doesn't exist, and as such you're getting an error that this is undefined.

```
if ($('#res_prop').is(':checked')) {
    var prop_type = $('#res_prop').val();
}
else if ($('#com_prop').is(':checked')) {
    var prop_type = $('#com_prop').val();
}
```

And change the line which reads `prop_type: $prop_type,` to `prop_type: prop_type,`

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Now I'm getting `undefined variable` for `$test` and `$pagination`. I think the script is wrong, the success is inside data anyways I don't need that callback, just execute the hide/show(). Where can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import the `<div class="results"></div>` container with ajax:

you should use this tested and working code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search, .pagination').click(function() { // search button and change page
        $prop_type = '';

        if ($('#res_prop').is(':checked')) {
            $prop_type = $('#res_prop').val();
        }
        else if ($('#com_prop').is(':checked')) {
            $prop_type = $('#com_prop').val();
        }

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "go.php",
            data: { 
                'prop_type': $prop_type, 
                'city': $('select[name="city"]').val(),
                'zone': $('select[name="zone"]').val() 
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            var _html = $.parseHTML(data);
            $('.cont-1').hide();
            $('.cont-2').show();
            $(_html).each(function(i, el) {
                if (el.className == 'results') {
                    $('.results').html($(el).html());
                };
            });
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It's still not working, maybe is a url problem. I have .htaccess rules to redirect to index.php, i'm using dynamic links (in this case "/search" but i've already tried it). Any idea? I'm getting undefined index: `echo $_POST['prop_type'];`

Comment: The code above is tested and it's working, so firstly check the url and change it to `url: "http://website.com/search",`, secondly if you are redirecting to the home page you will not see the changes, so stop this rule from the htaccess, and finally can you please copy the whole error. Also you can `console.log(data)` in the `.done(function(data){console.log(data)})` to see whats returning the php search file.

Comment: Ok the url is /search. I did alert(data); and I can see the whole html code, i can see `echo 'prop type: ' . $_POST['prop_type'];` it's working but just in the alert, in the page i still see undefined index... What's wrong?

Comment: is undefined index a javascript or a php error? If it is a Javascript error please copy the whole error here, if it is a php error then it's not from the script, it is from something else in your php code.

Comment: It's a php error: `Notice: Undefined index: prop_type`. I think the problem is that data is not printed in the html, doesn't jquery do that automatically?

Comment: Please copy and paste your full search page code in your post. And is it writen on which line is the error?

Comment: It's already pasted, there's no more (aside from html). I mean there's the actual processed page, then I send ajax post and it returns the new processed html code (inside data) but it's not printed in the actual page. I think that's the problem?

Comment: Also there's no error, just the notice because the current page does not receive the data. Inside data there's no `Notice: Undefined index: prop_type`, it's working but in the current page it's not working. Sorry i'm a noob using ajax. What I don't know if Ajax just return data but does not refresh the actual page with the new data?

Comment: I don't know why but it's not working... You mean the parent div? or which one? I created one with class results but nothing :(